# Is md5's padding the same that sh256?

Tags: algorithm, hash, md5, padding, sha256

I am trying to code in C both algorithms md5 and sha256 using the multiple documentations I found on the internet. 
My md5 seems to work fine, but not my sha256.

Here is what I am trying to figure out, Is the padding step exactly the same for both of those algorithms or am I missing something ?

```
echo -n toto | ./md5
01110100 01101111 01110100 01101111 10000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000
f71dbe52628a3f83a77ab494817525c6

echo -n "toto" | ./sha256
01110100 01101111 01110100 01101111 10000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00100000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
00000000
cda8272de630c5dd9770c5f5030d2d53650b6e986229d21291c5803ff4da592c
```

Here is my data after padding, the md5 is fine with this, but sha256 is not, and I am wondering if my error could come from a misunderstanding of this step.
thank you !

Answer (score 0):

When you add message length (after padding) MD5 uses little-endian, but SHA256 uses big-endian. Paddings are not the same.